# GWT graphics library

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, webgl

I'm looking for a graphics library made for designing games in GWT preferably with `webGL` and `canvas fallback`. I didn't find any one that fits my needs yet.

**PlayN:** has nice support over many devices and HTML5 fallback, but lacks advanced features even with TriplePlay

**GWT ports of Three.js**: https://github.com/vatula/gwt.threejs, https://github.com/blimster/net.blimster.gwt.threejs/, those run twice as slow as Three.js itself.

I'm looking for a graphics library for game development in GWT with advanced features such as particle systems, blending, sprite sheets, ... which is not running significantly slower than the javascript implementation without GWT. This graphics library should be able to run `webGL` with `canvas fallback` preferably for performance reasons. The library would only be used for `2D` manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from playn, the most important project supporting GWT is [libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645187/gwt-graphics-library). I tried it some time ago and it has plenty of utilities, tools, etc.

Games produced with this library can be compiled to a lot of outputs, included GWT to produce the HTML5 game version.

AFAIK, they only support javascript/webGL.